# issue "unexpectedly found nil" with downloading image from firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an issue when I'm downloading an image from firebase here is my code:

```
func getuser(){

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).child("credentials").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = value?["name"] as! String
        let email = value?["email"] as! String
        let profilePicLink = value?["profilePicLink"] as? String ?? ""


        Variables.userName = name as String
        Variables.userEmail = email as String
        self.username.text = Variables.userName
        print(profilePicLink)
        // Create a storage reference from the URL
        let storageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: profilePicLink)
        // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 *  1000 * 1000 ) { (data, error) -> Void in

            let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.img.image = pic

        }



    })


}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
==> this the link as printed https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eswitch-72b56.appspot.com/o/usersProfilePics%2FKYe6fIQReNM8Oog4ELOdRLsC99J3?alt=media&token=6f2392bc-d35b-4ebc-b2c1-2dc34bc4b95a
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The error that I'm getting is in this line

```
let storageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: profilePicLink)
```

below is my snapshot readings:

```
snap (credentials) {
    email = "bilal@me.com";
    mobile = 50955514;
    name = Bilal;
    profilePicLink = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eswitch-72b56.appspot.com/o/usersProfilePics%2FKYe6fIQReNM8Oog4ELOdRLsC99J3?alt=media&token=6f2392bc-d35b-4ebc-b2c1-2dc34bc4b95a";
    role = user;
}
```

Thanks

Here is the solution:

Added this line to func viewDidLoad()

```
storage = FIRStorage.storage()
```

Comment: Are you sure `self.storage` is initialised?

Comment: Why does that matter if profilePicLink variable is optional or not for  self.storage.reference? Maybe self.storage is not defined or problem is somewhere else.

Comment: wow how I missed that! Thank you! I added storage =  FIRStorage.storage() to func viewDidLoad()

Comment: @BilalBaydoun please add the solution as an answer to this question for future reference.

Comment: can you post your comment as an answer thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that `self.storage` is initialized.

```
storage = FIRStorage.storage()
```